# Do my dying soldiers live if I end the mission before stabilizing them?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Say that I have a soldier who is dying, and I get the message saying that I have three turns to stabilize them or they die.

If I finish the mission before then, do they live? If I don't have any medpacs handy, is it worth trying to rush to finish the mission in the hopes that they'll fight another day?

Comment: I haven't played the original in a while, but IIRC the answer is "yes, they live"

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Do you want to turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they'll survive.

If you're sure you're on the final group of aliens, finishing the mission early is a valid tactic for saving them. Trying to rush the mission is also a great way to get more soldiers killed of course, so bear that in mind.

Comment: Is this still the case if XCOM evacs at the end of the mission?

Comment: @RoijanEskor Yes, it should be.  If the mission ends by any means *other than all XCOM agents dying* then the still-bleeding wounded should live.  Note that I'm pretty sure this was done differently in *XCOM 2.*

Comment: @Steve-O Ok. In XCOM 2, if you leave a bleeding -out soldier in the field when you evac, he will be MIA.

Comment: @RoijanEskor Though this only applies to evac. If you end the mission by killing all enemies, they're fine.

Comment: Realizing this is a long dead post, but in Enemy Unknown/Within, if you evac, any soldier that isn't in the evac zone is MIA.  If your soldier was bleeding out in the evac zone (which would require them to get shot while already there), they would probably live, but if they're out on the battlefield somewhere, they'll be MIA.